# How to do with javascript, that when click on href, it's show text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have got this code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">Show comments</a><br>
<div id="myContent">
    My text1
</div>
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">Show comments</a><br>
<div id="myContent">
   My text2
</div>
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">Show comments</a><br>
<div id="myContent">
   My text3
</div>
```

My style.css code:

```
#myContent {
   display: none;
}
```

I want that, when I click on first **Show comments**, that to show first text (My text1), then I click on second **Show comments**, that to show second text (My text2), then I click on third **Show comments**, that to how third text (My text3).
And such a code is a lot.

How to do, that don't be:
Click on second **Show comments** don't show me first text, but show me second text? How to adapt?

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML. Stop using duplicate IDs. Use classes instead.

Comment: How to do that? Change from this: `$("#"+divId).toggle();` to  `$("."+divId).toggle();` ?

Comment: @Deimantas How to do what? Just Google how HTML class names work and how to use them with jQuery.

Comment: Changing `#` to `.` isn’t the only thing you need to do. You need to use `class` instead of `id` and you need to select a specific DIV with that class.

Comment: But then I click on any **Show comments** it's show all text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Prev or Next jquery:

```
  <a class="showMessage">Show comments</a>
    <div class="myContent">
        My text1
    </div><br><br>

  <a class="showMessage">Show comments</a>
    <div class="myContent">
       My text2
    </div><br><br>

  <a class="showMessage">Show comments</a>
    <div class="myContent">
       My text3
    </div>

$(".showMessage").click(function(ev){
$(this).next().toggle();
})
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zm3Lg85a/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=zm3Lg85a

Comment: `$(this).next().next().toggle();` would preserve the original HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `#myContent` divs a unique identifier.

Comment: But I have got many code, I can't to do many unique divs identifier.

Comment: @Deimantas you aren't getting it ... You **can't** use the same ID for **more than one** tag. No matter what you try to do : ID is unique. That's how it works :)

Comment: And it doesn't matter how many there are, you can always keep adding numbers to the end of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Ids must be uniques:

```
    <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent1');">Show comments</a><br>
    <div id="myContent1">
        My text1
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent2');">Show comments</a><br>
    <div id="myContent2">
        My text2
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent3');">Show comments</a><br>
    <div id="myContent3">
       My text3
    </div>
```

By the way, it's better to use click event. `<a onclick="toggleDiv('anId')">Show comments</a>`

You can go with something else:

```
<div>
    <a onclick="toggle(this);">Show comments</a><br>
    <div>
        My text1
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a onclick="toggle(this);">Show comments</a><br>
    <div>
        My text2
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a onclick="toggle(this);">Show comments</a><br>
    <div>
       My text3
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript toggle function could use jquery:

```
function toggle(element){
    $(element).parent().find('div').toggle();
}
```

Something like that would be easier to maintain.
*Not tested.*

Comment: Avoid to use ids when you can. Ids a unique for the whole page. Classes are better, but if you avoid using both of them it's even better. `this` helps a lot. After that you can move in you dom from your element and find what you want.